# Can System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader use a different image then one from the main ImageList?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist, columnheader

I have an ListView set up to sort, and I have that working well.

However, when the ListView is sorted, no indication is provided as to the current sort column and order.

I tried a solution setting the ColumnHeader.ImageKey property whenever sorting, but I want to be able to use images that aren't the size specified by the ListView's SmallImageList.

Is there any way to do this *without* using OwnerDraw mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without OwnerDraw. However, OwnerDraw isn't as bad as you might think. There are many examples on [CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/); like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/aa_listview.aspx)

Comment: Okay, although those CodeProject links were no help, I think OwnerDraw might be what I need.  Besides, it might even help me solve some other minor problems I've been having!  :-)